# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MicroBlink.framework/MicroBlink

Tags: ios, xcode, microblink, blinkid

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MicroBlink.framework/MicroBlink

Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F6A7AA6C-73C0-479C-8E6B-C679D3C1E515/text.app/text

Reason: image not found

Comment: Do you have the framework embedded in your app?

Comment: Are you building MicroBlink from source, fetching it from CocoaPods, from Carthage or some other source?

Comment: Yes I have @PhillipMills

Comment: From GitHub download and drag and drop @MikeGer

Answer (score 3):

MicroBlink.framework is a dynamic framework and as such you need to embed it in the app's bundle.

Here are the generic instructions about embedding frameworks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7KhnHdOs6A

Comment: Adding all frameworks to Embedded Binaries worked for me.